# How to SELECT DISTINCT records with INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables Finance Commissions May2021 (FMAY) and Consolidated Client Codes (CCC).

Here is the code for Insert Into: For table FMAY

```
 USE [FinanceCommissions26May2021]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Finance_Commissions_May26_2021$]    Script Date: 22/06/2021 11:06:26 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Finance_Commissions_May26_2021$](
    [Lender Reference] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [F2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [F3] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Client] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [F5] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Supplier] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Settlement / Inception Date] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Base Value] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Original Loan Amount] [money] NULL,
    [Adviser Split (%)*] [money] NULL,
    [F12] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Supplier_Amount_(incl GST)] [money] NULL,
    [Supplier_Amount_(GST)] [money] NULL,
    [Adviser Share (ex GST)] [money] NULL,
    [F16] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [F17] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Adviser Share (GST)] [money] NULL,
    [Adviser Share (incl GST)] [money] NULL,
    [LastNameOnly] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FirstNameOnly] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FirstFourLastName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ClientCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IndexMatch] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [F25] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [F26] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

#### FMAY

Table FMAY contains the following columns:

- commission amounts
- a Lender Reference Number
- client names (LastName, FirstName).

This report comes in monthly and contains monthly commissions for some of the clients (usually contains 350-400 records).

```
CREATE TABLE [Finance_Commissions_May26_2021$] (
    CommissionAmount,
    LenderReferenceNumber,
    ClientLastName,
    ClientFirstName
)
```

& here is the code for table CCC:

```
USE [FinanceCommissions26May2021]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Consolidated_ClientCodes$]    Script Date: 22/06/2021 11:07:27 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consolidated_ClientCodes$](
    [FirstFourLastName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ClientCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Client] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

#### CCC

Table CCC contains the following columns:

- client names

  - (different format though - i.e. FirstName,LastName)
- a client code (which is a unique identifier (Primary key) assigned to each client.

  - Client code takes the form of `SMIT123`.
  - e.g. for "John, Smith" it's `SMIT123`
  - for "Mark, Smith" it's `SMIT345`, and so on.
  - i.e. First Four letters of last name followed by a **unique** 3 digit code.

This table contains Client names and unique Client codes for ALL clients (more than 7000 records)

```
CREATE TABLE ['20210617145928-Exception - No C$'] (
    ClientCode PRIMARY KEY, -- '\w\w\w\w\d\d\d'
    FirstName,
    LastName
)
```

### The problem

My aim is : To assign this unique Client code to each client within the FMAY table.

Since there was NO common column between tables `FMAY` and `CCC`, I created a new column (`FirstFourLastName`) which parses out `FirstFour` letters of Last Name (like "`SMIT`") from both Tables.

Then using this new column (`FirstFourLastName`), I wrote code for Inner Join in SQL with an aim to assign the Unique "Client Code" to each record in table FMAY.

I am able to get the correct  client code assigned but not able to ONLY select distinct records.

My code is:

```
select
    FMAY.[Lender Reference],
    CCC.Client,
    CCC.ClientCode,
    FMAY.FirstFourLastName,
    FMAY.[Adviser Share (ex GST)],
    FMAY.[Adviser Share (GST)],
    FMAY.[Adviser Share (incl GST)],
    FMAY.Product 
from
    [FinanceCommissions26May2021].[dbo].[Finance_Commissions_May26_2021$] FMAY
    inner join [FinanceCommissions26May2021].[dbo].['20210617145928-Exception - No C$'] CCC on
        FMAY.FirstFourLastName = CCC.FirstFourLastName
```

The above code is giving me 6300 records, with the correct client code attached to each record though! However, I only need to assign Client Code to the 350-400 records in the FMAY table.

How can I select distinct records for my problem please?

Comment: Please post your **actual** `CREATE TABLE` statements instead of giving us an English-language description of the table.

Comment: I added my estimations of what your `CREATE TABLE` statements are, however it's unclear from your posting if the `ClientFirstName` and `ClientLastName` values are in separate columns or are packed into a single column. Also, what ETL process are you using? It looks like you imported this from a CSV file or Excel workbook... so what other data is in the source that you could be using?

Comment: "The above code is giving me 6300 records, with the correct client code attached to each record though! However, I only need to assign Client Code to the 350-400 records in the FMAY table." - we really need concrete examples of the data you're working with to investigate an unexpected `JOIN` output.

Comment: Hi Dai,Thanks for your response. I did not create the table from scratch - just imported it from an Excel sheet.

Comment: No, Client First Name and Client Last Name are in the same column in the original table. However, there wasn't any other column which is common between the two tables (FMAY and CCC), so I created a new column in both FMAY and CCC with First four letters of client's last name (& called this new column "FirstFourLastName"). I then used this as the common column. Sorry, I did NOT create the table so don't have any CREATE TABLE statements to share.

Comment: You can get `CREATE TABLE` statements from SSMS. Open the Object Explorer > Your Database > Tables > Right-click > Script As INSERT to...

Comment: Thanks Dai. I have attached the code in my original question.

Comment: I made a mistake in my comment, I meant "Script as CREATE to", not "Script as INSERT", sorry. You'll need to update your post again.

Comment: We need a [MRE] i.e. the smallest amount of code + data which reproduces the issue. As it stands its too complex.

Comment: please provide sample data with insert scripts and output you need in tabular format.

Comment: Is there a way to attach/ include a screenshot or copy/paste from an Excel/csv file in Stackoverflow forums? If so, I can try to include data and output here for your reference. Thank you everyone for your help and time. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be multiple similar values for FirstFourLastName and with join on FirstFourLastName you're getting every combination possible. For example:

FMAY table

| LenderReference | FirstFourLastName |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | smit |
| 456 | smit |

CCC Table

| clientcode | FirstFourLastName |
| --- | --- |
| smit123 | smit |
| smit456 | smit |

Omitting all other columns, the inner join on FirstFourLastName would produce:

| LenderReference | clientcode | FirstFourLastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | smit123 | smit |
| 123 | smit456 | smit |
| 456 | smit123 | smit |
| 456 | smit456 | smit |

I would double check that the clientcode is definitely attaching correctly. If LenderReference is unique, you could run distinct count of clientcodes against it.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I checked and the Clientcode is attaching correctly.  Also, LenderReference is unique in the FMAY table.  So it should only a matter of identifying Distinct LenderReference.  I tried using Select Distinct on LenderReference but keep getting errors, I also tried using Over (Partition by) but getting error on it too.                                       
 Should I be using Select distinct or Distinct Count OR should I try using Over (Partition by) to ensure my output doesn't list the same record multiple times?

Comment: I would run:

SELECT DISTINCT 
FMAY.[Lender Reference], 
COUNT(DISTINCT CCC.ClientCode)

FROM
    [FinanceCommissions26May2021].[dbo].[Finance_Commissions_May26_2021$] FMAY
    inner join [FinanceCommissions26May2021].[dbo].['20210617145928-Exception - No C$'] CCC on
        FMAY.FirstFourLastName = CCC.FirstFourLastName
  
GROUP BY FMAY.[Lender Reference]
Order By COUNT(DISTINCT CCC.ClientCode) DESC

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code! I am now getting the number of times each LenderReference appears in the table. However, I am looking to get an output where the FMAY table is reproduced with the respective client code (from CCC table) incorporated in. Can I now use this output that your code has generated to do an Inner Join with my initial query result to obtain a table with Lender reference, Client name, etc but the most important column to incorporate into my result is the ClientCode. I believe your code has brought me back quite close to what I am needing. Just one more step to go I think?

Comment: Would you mind sharing some of the results you're getting from that code please? It's showing the number of times each lender reference is showing, you're right. But the main point is that it shows that many lender references have several different client codes attached to them.

Comment: I don't really see a good reliable way to match the correct clientcode and only the correct clientcode for each lender reference with current setup. For CCC table, are the three digits in the clientcode generated randomly or there is some controllable logic? If there is a controllable logic, I would recommend using it on the FMAY table instead of FirstFourLastName. , I would also recommend using more identifying data besides the last name to create client code. Maybe first 4 of last name first 3 of first name or some other information specific to the client.

Comment: unfortunately we cannot alter the "Clientcode"  each client as that is widely used across the organisation and  i am unable to alter that. I also cannot change the way Clientcode is assigned as it is being done outside my purview of work. however, we do NOT need to include the Lender Reference number in the final output. So in other words, the key columns for the desired output are: Client Name, Client Code, Adviser Share (excl GST), Adviser share (GST), Adviser Share (Incl GST).  Remaining columns are not needed. Given that Lender Reference No. column isn't needed - would it simplify things?

Comment: I believe it's worthy of giving it a try? If a client has more than one advisor, you could still see a few extra rows, but not as many as before and those should be easy to identify. Good Luck!!